# keyboard shortcut for title case in word 2010

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Title Case' in Word 2010? If not, how can I create one?

I do know of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for 'Change Case', but this shortcut toggles through uppercase, lowercase and title case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create shortcuts, either use the ALT navigation or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> multiple times,
there shouldn't be a problem pressing a keyboard shortcut twice to reach Title Case...

What you can do is create a quick access item and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> with a number, [see this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA012341051033.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I found a useful macro template at http://word.tips.net/T000215_Intelligent_Title_Case.html .

Reproduced here:

```
Sub TitleCase()
    Dim lclist As String
    Dim wrd As Integer
    Dim sTest As String

    ' list of lowercase words, surrounded by spaces
    lclist = " of the by to this is from a "

    Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord

    For wrd = 2 To Selection.Range.Words.Count
        sTest = Trim(Selection.Range.Words(wrd))
        sTest = " " & LCase(sTest) & " "
        If InStr(lclist, sTest) Then
            Selection.Range.Words(wrd).Case = wdLowerCase
        End If
    Next wrd
End Sub
```

This macro lets you adjust titles so that words of your choice (typically short words, conjunctions, etc.) are not capitalized.

See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized
for detailed comments on capitalization styles.

Answer (score 0):

To change the first letter as upper case select the word or sentence you want to change and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> once.

If you press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> twice then the whole sentence will be changed. This key is for both upper and lower cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own shortcuts (technically a macro, but practically a shortcut) quite easily.  Simply create a macro and assign it a button or keyboard combo.  If all you need to do is turn on Title Case quickly, there's no need to write VBA code for something this simple.

- Under the Developer tab on the left side is the Record Macro button.
- Click that and you'll get a Record Macro popup.
- Assign the macro a name and pick 'button' or 'keyboard' and assign your shortcut key(s).
- Once you hit close after assigning the key, the macro is recording.
- Go to the home tab > Font section > Change Case drop-down and choose Title Case.
- Then return to the Developer tab and hit Stop recording.

Now your shortcut will repeat that sequence and turn any word or words you've selected to Title Case.