# Word VBA macro to convert selected text to title case, ignoring "excepted" words that follow a colon

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

For converting selected text in Microsoft Word to title case, I found the following useful macro at: [keyboard shortcut for title case in word 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/164707/keyboard-shortcut-for-title-case-in-word-2010/643513#643513)

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the macro so that it always capitalizes a word the follows a colon, even if the word is on the "exceptions" list (e.g., and, of, in, the).

```
Sub TitleCase()
Dim lclist As String
Dim wrd As Integer
Dim sTest As String

' list of lowercase words, surrounded by spaces
lclist = " of the by to is from a and but as at in "

Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord

For wrd = 2 To Selection.Range.Words.Count
    sTest = Trim(Selection.Range.Words(wrd))
    sTest = " " & LCase(sTest) & " "
    If InStr(lclist, sTest) Then
        Selection.Range.Words(wrd).Case = wdLowerCase
    End If
Next wrd
End Sub
```

For example, if the following text were selected, "this is my title: **the** subtitle goes here", the result would be: "This Is My Title: **The** Subtitle Goes Here", even though "the" is on the exceptions list.

Comment: You could take the word `the` out of the list.

Comment: See http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/24807-how-do-i-convert-line-text-title.html#post78192. See http://www.gmayor.com/word_vba_examples_2.htm. I'm not sure that either of these consider the possibility of embeded-sentence titles. Consider changing the colon to a semi-colon. The first one has a much more extensive list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised your code so it would ignore the word after a colon.

```
Sub TitleCase()
Dim lclist As String
Dim wrd As Integer
Dim sTest As String
Dim skipNext As Boolean

' list of lowercase words, surrounded by spaces
lclist = " of the by to is from a and but as at in "

Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord

For wrd = 2 To Selection.Range.words.Count
    sTest = Trim(Selection.Range.words(wrd))
    Select Case sTest
        Case ":"
            skipNext = True
        Case Else
            If skipNext = True Then
                skipNext = False
            Else
                sTest = " " & LCase(sTest) & " "
                If InStr(lclist, sTest) Then
                    Selection.Range.words(wrd).Case = wdLowerCase
                End If
            End If
    End Select
Next wrd
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Rich! This will be hugely helpful in my work. Much appreciated.